# e.stopPropagation() is not working for html:submit Struts tag

Tags: jquery, html, struts

In the last couple of hours I tried to find a solution but I didn't succeded. Long story in short, I have a form and I don't want to submit it:

```
<html:form  action="/saveZone.do" method="POST" styleId="mainForm">
...some code...

<html:submit  styleId="formSaveButton" styleClass="utl_button"  > <bean:message key="domain.popup.save.button"/> </html:submit>

</html:form>
```

In my script I have:

```
 jQuery("#formSaveButton").click(function(event)
       {   
   ..some code
if ((globalFlag1==false) || (globalFlag2==false))
              {
               event.preventDefault();             
                return false;
              }else{
                return true;
                unloadPopupModal('#popup_box_parent','.popup_box');
              }
 });
```

In debug mode I hit the line with  `event.preventDefault();` but my form is still submited. If someone can find what is the problem it will be godlike for me. Thanks!

P.S. I use IE8 and I also tried

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery("#formSaveButton").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* some code */
    if ((globalFlag1 == false) || (globalFlag2 == false)) {
        /* some code */
    } else {
        jQuery("#formSaveButton").submit(); /* submit the form or whatever... */
    }
});
```